# How to eliminate the space following the conjunction "and" in a Hebrew localization of a biblatex bibliography?

Tags: biblatex, hebrew

The following LaTeX code was saved in `~/Test.tex`.

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{hebook,
   author = {אריק and בנץ},
   title = {כותרת},
   year = {2022}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{hebrew.lbx}
\ProvidesFile{hebrew.lbx}
[\abx@lbxid]
\DeclareRedundantLanguages{hebrew}{hebrew}
\DeclareBibliographyStrings{and = {{ו}{ו}}}
\endinput
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bidi=basic,hebrew,provide=*]{babel}
\babelfont{rm}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{FreeSans}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{hebook}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The code creates a file named `Test.bib` containing a BibTex bibliography consisting of a single entry: a book written by two authors. The code then creates a file named `hebrew.lbx` containing `biblatex` localization strings for the `hebrew` locale. This file contains only one entry: the Hebrew word for the conjunction `and`, the conjunction used, e.g., between two authors. The code then creates a simple article, whose main language is established, via the `babel` package, to be Hebrew. The body of the article contains a reference to the bibliography entry, and a bibliography.

Then the following commands were executed in the Terminal.

```
> cd ~
> lualatex Test
> biber Test
> lualatex Test
```

Consequently the file `~/Test.pdf` was generated. When opened in a PDF viewer, the file displayed as follows. (I captured in the screenshot only the relevant part of the display.)

[image: Hebrew bibliography containing a book with two authors]

(Note that Hebrew is a right-to-left language.)

As can be seen, the output is as expected. All is well, then, right? Not quite. The problem is that in Hebrew, unlike in European languages, the conjunction *and* is not a standalone word, but rather a particle that is attached as a prefix to the following word (i.e. the word to its *left*, since Hebrew is a right-to-left language). However, as the screenshot shows, the Hebrew conjunction is treated as a standalone word, and is separated from the following author's name by a space.

How can this space be eliminated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

After the specified tokens there are some biblatex helper macros, then `\space` so you can insert a macro that looks ahead and gobbles space.

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{hebook,
   author = {אריק and בנץ},
   title = {כותרת},
   year = {2022}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{hebrew.lbx}
\ProvidesFile{hebrew.lbx}
[\abx@lbxid]
\DeclareRedundantLanguages{hebrew}{hebrew}
\DeclareBibliographyStrings{and = {{ו\foo}{ו\foo}}}
\endinput
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bidi=basic,hebrew,provide=*]{babel}
\babelfont{rm}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{FreeSans}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\def\foo#1\space{#1}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{hebook}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. However, one day hopefully the `hebrew.lbx` file will be part of the `biblatex` distribution, in which case the `\foo` command would need to be a part of the `.lbx` file, not of the `.tex` file. How can this be accomplished? I tried to move the `\foo` definition to the top of the `.lbx` file, just after the `\ProvidesFile` line, and it didn't work.

Comment: you could add it to the lbx I think (you may need `\gdef` not `\def`) but anyway if proposing to add to biblatex, flag this with the maintainers they could probably add an option (or there may be one already) that prevents `\space` being added rather than removing it later.